# How do I stop Google Sheet to make a formula when I'm using + sign?

Tags: google-sheets

I know that just putting a space or an apostrophe is the go-to but I have a dependent drop-down list and whenever I select +75 in the dropdown menu it makes a formula out of it, even though the source data has an apostrophe, is there any setting or some script that would block this?

[image: the dropdown list]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use the Unicode `﹢` SMALL PLUS SIGN instead of the regular `+` PLUS SIGN. They look almost the same, but the `﹢` character does not get interpreted as the mathematical plus sign.